# colspan question and help

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table

Im currently coding an email and cant get my colspans to work, i just cant understand how they are supposed to work so if anyone could explain how you have multiple rows with multiple columns at different sizes then I would appreciate it loads!

Here is the code Iv been retying to set

```
 <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
        <td width="185" height="50" bgcolor="grey">Title 1</td>
        <td width="415" height="50" bgcolor="red">Title 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="600" height="50" bgcolor="pink" colspan="2">Title 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="365" height="50" bgcolor="grey">Title 4</td>
        <td width="235" height="50" bgcolor="orange">Title 5</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Can you describe more clearly in what way it's failing for you?  Maybe include a small screen grab?

Comment: Yup, seems good, see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYuyb/)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. What are you really want to know. See here to know more about tables http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Comment: Its not correct though, the first table row cells should be 185px wide and 415px wide and the 3rd table row cells should be 365px wide and 235px wide, at the moment both these rows cells are identical in width - 280px and 320px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot explicitly set the width of the row column that contradicting to others. There's a work around here though the structure might looks ugly. Then please do read about [tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html) for better understanding.

For the work around you can set an invisible row that will occupy for the space you needed.

Se related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373893/colspan-width-problem)

Now for your problem you can try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/cWF33/

If your table structure is always like this. Have it change to table less. What I mean is use of div with css

Comment: Hi Ace, thanks for the reply. The reason Im a little foggy on table layout is because its something I never really use only when coding emails. Il read into this more though and thanks again!

Comment: I know it'll be clear to you. Also think about this table in html works like a cell in a spreadsheet. When you merge two cells in a row then what do you think will happen to other rows affected by the column? anyway I hope it did help you.