# <td> width not working with inline styles

Tags: css, html, html-table

I am not able to set the width properties on the `<td>` cells in the following table, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around why. I've tried using both literal `width="100"` and inline styles `width: 100px` & `max-width: 100px`, but for some reason certain cells are automatically generating widths that are wider than the `img` element they contain.

I'm just trying to limit the width of each `td` to the width of the `img` inside it, so that each row is the same width and the images align.

For context - this is a table containing image "slices" from photoshop. The inline styles are necessary because this is for an email signature in Gmail and Outlook (I understand why that's generally a bad idea, but the client is boss on that point, and I'm only concerned with the table alignment in this question). **I changed the table background color to lime** to help with debugging.

**Edit**: I'm using a placeholder image here for the privacy of the client. I think the vertical "gaps" that were appearing between these images slices in Gmail have to do with the width of the table not being fixed. That's why I set the `table-layout` to `fixed` and was hoping that sizing each `<td>` to the image width and floating everything left would resolve the issue.

```html
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="192" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: lime;table-layout: fixed">
 <tbody width="600" style="display: table;max-width: 600px; width: 600px">
  <tr width="600" id="row1" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS20G.gif" width="600" height="114">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="600" id="row2" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="159" rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD36x.gif" width="159" height="18">
   </td>
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="152" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBCnK.gif" width="152" height="15" border="0"></a>
   </td>
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="289" rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZaBD.gif" width="289" height="18">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="600" id="row3" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="152" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xdce.gif" width="152" height="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="600" id="row4" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="137" rowspan="4" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1iQh.gif" width="137" height="59">
   </td>
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="181" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <a href="#">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34yid.gif" width="180" height="12" border="0"></a>
   </td>
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="283" rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t84fT.gif" width="283" height="39">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="600" id="row5" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="181" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/skKMN.gif" width="180" height="27">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="600" id="row6" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="139" rowspan="2" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbrAv.gif" width="139" height="20">
   </td>
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="161" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <a href="#">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDAp.jpg" width="161" height="14" border="0"></a>
   </td>
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="163" rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TpK3.gif" width="163" height="20">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="600" id="row7" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="161" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPqy.gif" width="161" height="6">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="600" id="row8" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
   <td>
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" width="137" height="1"></td>
   <td>
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" width="22" height="1"></td>
   <td>
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" width="117" height="1"></td>
   <td>
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" width="35" height="1"></td>
   <td>
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" width="6" height="1"></td>
   <td>
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" width="120" height="1"></td>
   <td>
    <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" width="163" height="1"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit #2:**

I'm able to get closer by removing the fixed table layout altogether, but the cells are still slightly wider than the img inside them (note the green space to the right of each `<td>`):

```html
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="192" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: lime;">

  <tr id="row1" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="7" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 600px; height: auto;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS20G.gif" alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; height: 18px; width: 100%;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD36x.gif" alt=" "></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <a target="_blank " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
        <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; height: 15px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBCnK.gif" border="0 " alt=" "></a>
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="3 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: auto;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZaBD.gif" alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 152px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xdce.gif" height="3 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rowspan="4 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 137px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1iQh.gif" height="59 " alt=" "></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="4 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <a href="#" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
        <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 181px;cursor: pointer;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34yid.gif" height="12 " border="0 " alt=" "></a>
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 283px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t84fT.gif" height="39 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row5" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="4 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 181px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/skKMN.gif" height="27 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row6" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 140px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDAp.jpg" height="20 " alt=" "></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="3 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <a href="#">
        <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0;width: 161px;cursor: pointer;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDAp.jpg" height="14 " border="0 " alt=" "></a>
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 163px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPqy.gif" height="20" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row7" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="3" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 161px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPqy.gif" height="6 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row8" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width:22px; height: 0px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" alt="">
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 117px; height: 0px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 35px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 6px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 120px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 163px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You seem to have 7 columns but never state how wide each column is and also your first column always seems to span 2 - is that needed?  I would start by sorting out your table layout and simplifying it.  Then sort out your images - some of them are overflowing their columns.  If you had an image of how the final table should look, it would be a great help

Comment: I'd say remove all `width` attributes from the table, especially from the tr elements, and put in 7 `col` elements having the correct width.

Comment: Does this question solve the problem? [Html <td> width issue. Is it related to colspan? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562347/html-td-width-issue-is-it-related-to-colspan-how)

Comment: Way too many inline styles. Makes the code a lot more cluttered.

Comment: Please read the details: The inline styles are necessary because this is for an email signature in Gmail and Outlook

Comment: @Mark did you give a try to my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if that fits your request, but in order to align those images i found ones that were creating the gap cause of larger td element and i set them to width: 100% (as in your example seems like 1px is added to td).

As you can see the strange table cell width remains but it is fully filled by images, so the "mosaic" image doesn't look like a mosaic.

```html
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="192" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: lime;">

  <tr id="row1" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="7" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 100%; height: auto;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS20G.gif" alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; height: 18px; width: 100%;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD36x.gif" alt=" "></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <a target="_blank " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
        <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; height: 15px;float:left;width:100%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBCnK.gif" border="0 " alt=" "></a>
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="3 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: auto;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZaBD.gif" alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 100%;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xdce.gif" height="3 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rowspan="4 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 137px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1iQh.gif" height="59 " alt=" "></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="4 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <a href="#" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
        <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 181px;cursor: pointer;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34yid.gif" height="12 " border="0 " alt=" "></a>
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 283px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t84fT.gif" height="39 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row5" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="4 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 181px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/skKMN.gif" height="27 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row6" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="2 " rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 140px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDAp.jpg" height="20 " alt=" "></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="3 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <a href="#">
        <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0;width: 161px;cursor: pointer;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDAp.jpg" height="14 " border="0 " alt=" "></a>
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rowspan="2 " style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0 " style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 163px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPqy.gif" height="20" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row7" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="3" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 161px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPqy.gif" height="6 " alt=" "></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row8" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;" width="600">
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width:22px; height: 0px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" alt="">
    </td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 117px; height: 0px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 35px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 6px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 120px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="line-height: 0;font-size: 0px;">
      <img border="0" style="display:block;line-height: 0; width: 163px;float:left;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif" height="0" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your current code:

The vertical right-size green line is because on the row1 the image is 600 px wide and the table is 601 px wide, despite setting table width to 600, because the rows bellow are 601.

The vertical centered green line is because on row2 column 2 the image is 152 wide while below, on row3 the image is 153 wide.

The rest of the lines are 601 wide.

The bottom green line is because you set table height to 192 when it actually is 191.

I said "you" did this and that but maybe this is the way it was generated from photoshop!

Answer (score 0):

Because your images have all different height and width it's very complicated (if not impossible) to set up a table with the right colspans and rowspans. It would be better to setup multiple tables. I know the code below is not completely perfect, but I hope this helps.
As you can see, you can leave out all of your height/width settings.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
td {
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="t1">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS20G.gif"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="t2">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD36x.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBCnK.gif"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZaBD.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xdce.gif"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="t3">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1iQh.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34yid.gif"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t84fT.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/skKMN.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbrAv.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDAp.jpg"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TpK3.gif"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPqy.gif"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="t4">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rPU.gif"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```